# Can I install linux apps on external drive and use it on different machines with different linux distro?

Tags: dual-boot, distributions, external-hdd, application

I was thinking to upgrade my laptop with 500GB nvme drive and I want to multiboot different linux distros (also windows and macOS for software testing) in it.

So in order save space, can I install linux apps on external SSD and use it on different machine (laptop and pc) or different distro (mint, fedora, manjaro) that I boot with?

Comment: One possible solution is about using containers (such as podman or docker) for running a specific distro with the apps you want to use. For this task you will have to install docker or podman on the Linux hosts and change the container storage in the external SSD.

Comment: Another solution is by using `chroot` in your SSD, but I'm not sure it the SSD must have a distro installed. I've used `chroot` in my external hard drive which has installed a Linux distro, so I'm not sure if having an Linux OS is requirement.

Comment: You can make portable systems where you can install programs and store data files: a [persistent live](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) system or a [portable installed](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692) system in a USB drive. - The whole Linux system will be portable this way.

Answer (score 3):

In short, **No**.

Programs on the various distros are customised & compiled for each distro, and expect things like their config & data files to be in specific locations (which varies between distros according to the packaging policies of each - there are many similarities but also many incompatible differences), and for specific versions of the libraries they use to be available.

Software packages made for one distro are generally not compatible with other distros (even if they use the same package manager - e.g. a .deb package built for Ubuntu probably won't work well, or at all, on Mint or Debian).

You can try running software built for another distro on your system, but (except for the simplest of programs with few or no dependencies) it will probably either fail to work at all or (worse!) fail in subtle ways.

Best results come from not mixing software from different distros, or even different versions of the same distro (software built for one version of a distro is often built against the specific versions of libraries that may not be available in a different version of that distro, or may require a different version of the kernel).

Finally, while their implementation details differ in all sorts of subtle ways, there isn't all that much difference in using each distro or in the software available.

The most obvious difference between distros is in their default window manager / desktop environment (and background screens, font choices, window decorations, and other easily tweakable settings), but most of them allow you to freely choose and switch between them - e.g. Gnome is the default on many distros, but most of them make it easy to install XFCE or KDE or other desktop environments, and switch between them at will (if you have more than one installed, the graphical login screen will almost certainly have some way of letting you choose which one to use when you login, and to set one as your default - and each user on a system can have a different default).

My advice (once you've tried out a few to see which one you like best) is to pick one distro and stick with it.  There's little or no benefit to distro-hopping all the time.

Comment: Theoretically snaps could be used interchangeably *if* they could be "installed" outside of their predefined location and one could "register" them to the snap service.